# Any way to stop Url.RouteUrl from urlencoding route values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to output a placeholder within the url for client-side templating - {{>username}} but the placeholder gets url encoded automatically and the client-side templating breaks.

I can workaround it by passing in say 'username' and then string replacing it with '{{>username}}' and returning IHtmlString but this is far from elegant.

Was hoping for a better solution.

Any ideas Darin (or anyone else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlDecode(
    Url.RouteUrl(Model)
)
```

works for me, perhaps not any cleaner than your other solution.

*Test:*

Normal: `/Value=%3C%40%24(%5E%25%24`

Decoded: `/Value=<@$(^%$`